# having difficulties saving photos in react native project in react-native-vision-camera

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need advice on the issue I am having with saving photos in react native project in react-native-vision-camera

I am getting the following error

```
 ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'takePhoto' of undefined]
```

how do I handle the promise rejection and prevent it from happening and actually save the photo

See the code belowcode

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Camera,
  useCameraDevices,
  checkCameraPermissions,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import LoadingView from '../components/common/LoadingView';
import AppButton from '../components/common/AppButton';
import {RFPercentage} from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import Colors from '../config/colors';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import Screen from '../components/Screen';
import Loader from '../components/common/loader/loader';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

async function requestCameraPermissions() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Riders CameraScreen Camera Permission',
        message: 'Cool Photo CameraScreen needs access to your camera',
      },
    );
    if (granted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      throw new Error('Camera permission not granted.');
    }
  } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    await checkCameraPermissions();
  }
}

function CameraScreen({navigation}) {
  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.back;
  const [isCameraPermissionChecked, setCameraPermissionChecked] =
    useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const tokenStored = useSelector(state => state.token.tokenValue);
  const idStored = useSelector(state => state.userId.userIdValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermissions()
      .then(() => {
        setCameraPermissionChecked(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Alert.alert('Camera Permission Error', error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleTakePhoto = async () => {
    try {
      // Check if Camera.current is defined
      if (Camera.current) {
        // Take a photo
        const photo = await Camera.current.takePhoto({
          quality: 'high',
          flash: 'auto',
        });

        // Save the photo to local storage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('photo', photo.uri);
        Alert.alert(
          'Photo Taken',
          'Photo has been taken and saved to local storage.',
        );
      } else {
        // Camera.current is undefined
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          'The camera is not properly initialized or active.',
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'An error occurred while taking or saving the photo.',
      );
    }
  };

  if (!isCameraPermissionChecked) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (device == null) {
    return <LoadingView />;
  }

  return (
    <Screen style={styles.screen}>
      <Loader loading={loading} />
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.8}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}
          style={styles.closeButton}>
          <Entypo
            color={Colors.white}
            style={styles.closeIcon}
            name={'cross'}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Take A Photo</Text>
        <View style={styles.spacer} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Proof of Delivery(*)</Text>
        <AppButton
          onPress={handleTakePhoto}
          title="Take Picture"
          camera={true}
          padding={RFPercentage(1.5)}
          backgroundColor={'#afbfd8'}
          borderColor={Colors.white}
          borderWidth={RFPercentage(0.2)}
          color={Colors.white}
          bold={false}
          fontSize={RFPercentage(1.8)}
          borderRadius={RFPercentage(20)}
          width={'80%'}
        />
        <Camera style={styles.camera} device={device} isActive={true} />
        <AppButton
          onPress={handleTakePhoto}
          title="Submit"
          padding={RFPercentage(1.5)}
          backgroundColor="#90ce1a"
          borderColor={Colors.white}
          borderWidth={RFPercentage(0.2)}
          color={Colors.white}
          bold={false}
          fontSize={RFPercentage(1.8)}
          borderRadius={RFPercentage(20)}
          width="80%"
          style={styles.button}
        />
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: RFPercentage(7),
    backgroundColor: '#071b80',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: RFPercentage(2),
  },
  title: {
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: RFPercentage(2.1),
    fontWeight: '700',
    textAlign: 'center', // Center align the title
  },
  closeButton: {
    padding: RFPercentage(1),
  },
  closeIcon: {
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: RFPercentage(2.5),
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    marginVertical: RFPercentage(2),
    width: '100%',
    height: '70%',
  },
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 30,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

export default CameraScreen;
```

I am really new to react native and I appreciate every help I can get on this